# Uninstalling Office 2010 breaks Office 365 (Office 2013)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, office365

I have installed Office 365 alongside Office 2010 on a dozen or so Windows 7 machines, so that they may co-exist; and to mitigate the need to re-replace Office should there be any unforeseen incompatibility issues or user-hate toward Office 365.

Users of these machines have been pleased with Office 365 and no longer require 2010; whereby some have requested for Office 2010 to be removed from their computer. However, uninstalling Office 2010 from a computer which has Office 365 also installed (using click-to-run) somewhat breaks Office 365.

After 2010 has been removed, Office document icons are unknown (the default white icon for an unknown file are present) although they are configured in default programs to open in the correct office app (e.g. Word 2010 (desktop) to open .docx files). Double clicking such (unknown) document files does not open the "open with" dialogue box, but does nothing. Resetting default program settings also does not help. The only way to open office files is to open the respective application first and then open the document by using the open dialogue.

The only way I know to fix the problem is via a program offline repair (via programs and features). An office 365 online repair does not work, but results in error.

Is there a known method to uninstall office 2010 without breaking office 365 and needing to run a repair?

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! I wasn't aware of this issue and it seems to be a nasty one. I don't have an answer I'm afraid though I'd certainly like one since it might hit us sometime in the future. I'm guessing you don't have a MS Premier Support Agreement? I'd recommend raising an incident on your Office 365 tenancy AND asking a question in the appropriate [Office 365 forum](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/172.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. I will raise a support request with MS themselves tomorrow and see how they advise/respond. I will report back with my findings.

Comment: have you tried uninstalling both 2010 and 365 then re-installing 365?  Is file/program association the only issue?

Comment: Hi James. I was needing to mitigate the situation whereby no version of Office would be installed. Installing Office 365 before removing 2010 would have allowed this. Although not what I was hoping for, I have a response from Microsoft. Please see the question's answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Response from Microsoft:

> " We don't have any article\blog that says that it is not recommended to install Office 2013 along with Office 2010, but this article does states that:
>
> You can install Office 2013 alongside Office 2010 or the 2007 Microsoft Office system on Windows 7-based or Windows 8-based computers. This configuration is supported. However, for the best experience when you start to use Office 2013, we recommend that you uninstall any earlier version of Office.
>
> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2810106 "

Basically, there is no reference to the issue of uninstalling Office 2010 on a machine which has both Office 2010 and Office 365 installed. Presumably this also applies to Office 2007, based on the above MS response.

In conclusion, it is advisable to not install Office 365 alongside Office 2010 (or 2007) if you need/would like to remove Office 2010 at a later date - without uninstalling both products and re-installing Office 365 or repairing the broken O365 installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but here is the fix!!!!

For me this was 2010 versions of Word documents and publisher documents. Excel etc were all OK for some reason

I am running on Windows 7 so I know this worked for me....

So, here we go:

Right click the whited out icon > Properties > General Tab > Open With >  then in the new window Click the Browse Button

Navigate on your local drive to 
Program Files > Microsoft Office 15 > root > office15

then locate the relevant program - for Word it is called WINWORD

Then click OK or Apply

Your whited out icon will now be no longer white.

Hope this helps!!

Simon

Answer (score -1):

Just associating the file extension again did not work for me.
I had to uninstall Office 2013 cleaned the registry because the file associations were still there after the uninstalling process.
So, when I had it installed back, everything was working great.
The installation process took me about 10 minutes.
Hope you are as lucky as I was.

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall 2013, from what happen me just like above what worked for me was to restore office2010 and uninstall 2013, next you uninstall 2010 and install 2013. or for anyone just doing it for first time 2010 must be uninstalled before installing 2013.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, which was: "Is there a known method to uninstall office 2010 without breaking Office 365 and needing to run a repair?".

Comment: yes it is, you have to uninstall 2010 before uninstalling 2013 to avoid it. if you have already installed 2013 with 2010 you need to uninstall 2013, next you uninstall 2010 and install 2013 back on. its the only way of doing it without cause 2013 to brake